# Laravel - Not getting results from Eloquent query but ->toSql() gets results

Tags: laravel-5.4, eloquent

I have scoured SO regarding this issue but I can't seem to find what's causing my code not to return any result.  My issue is that if filter_job_title is queried, I do not get any result eventhough if I use SQL code genereated using ->toSql() and run it in phpmyadmin, I do see the correct result.  I need your eyes to see what's wrong with my code:

```
  $resumes = \App\Resume::select(\DB::raw("resumes.*, MATCH (resumes.job_title, resumes.career_summary, resumes.career_awards_and_achievements, resumes.school_or_institution) AGAINST ('{$k}' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance_1, MATCH (resume_section_experiences.exp_job_title, resume_section_experiences.exp_company, resume_section_experiences.exp_job_description) AGAINST ('{$k}' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance_2"))
  ->leftJoin('resume_section_experiences', 'resumes.user_id', '=', 'resume_section_experiences.user_id')
  ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'resumes.user_id')
  ->leftJoin('resume_section_languages', 'resume_section_languages.user_id', '=', 'resumes.user_id')
  ->leftJoin('resume_job_disciplines', 'resume_job_disciplines.user_id', '=', 'resumes.user_id')
  ->leftJoin('resume_job_functions', 'resume_job_functions.user_id', '=', 'resumes.user_id')
  ->whereRaw("(MATCH (resumes.job_title, resumes.career_summary, resumes.career_awards_and_achievements, resumes.school_or_institution) AGAINST ('{$k}' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH (resume_section_experiences.exp_job_title, resume_section_experiences.exp_company, resume_section_experiences.exp_job_description) AGAINST ('{$k}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND users.active = 1 AND users.privacy_level = 0", ['r1' => $k, 'r2' => $k])
  ->when(!empty($filter['filter_job_title']), function($query) use ($filter) {
    return $query->whereRaw('resume_section_experiences.exp_job_title LIKE "%?%"', $filter['filter_job_title']);        
  })
  ->groupBy("resumes.id")
  ->havingRaw('(relevance_1 + relevance_2) > 0')            
  ->orderByRaw("(relevance_1 + relevance_2) DESC, resumes.job_title ASC")
  ->simplePaginate(15); //toSql();//simplePaginate(15);
```

This is the SQL code generated using ->toSql(), formatted for easier view:

```
select resumes.*, 
MATCH (resumes.job_title, resumes.career_summary, resumes.career_awards_and_achievements, resumes.school_or_institution) AGAINST ('engineer' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance_1, 
MATCH (resume_section_experiences.exp_job_title, resume_section_experiences.exp_company, resume_section_experiences.exp_job_description) AGAINST ('engineer' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance_2 
from `resumes` 
left join `resume_section_experiences` on `resumes`.`user_id` = `resume_section_experiences`.`user_id` 
left join `users` on `users`.`id` = `resumes`.`user_id` 
left join `resume_section_languages` on `resume_section_languages`.`user_id` = `resumes`.`user_id` 
left join `resume_job_disciplines` on `resume_job_disciplines`.`user_id` = `resumes`.`user_id` 
left join `resume_job_functions` on `resume_job_functions`.`user_id` = `resumes`.`user_id` 
where (
MATCH (
resumes.job_title, resumes.career_summary, resumes.career_awards_and_achievements, resumes.school_or_institution) 
   AGAINST ('engineer' IN BOOLEAN MODE
) 
OR MATCH (
resume_section_experiences.exp_job_title, resume_section_experiences.exp_company, resume_section_experiences.exp_job_description) 
   AGAINST ('engineer' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) 
AND users.active = 1 
AND users.privacy_level = 0 
AND resume_section_experiences.exp_job_title LIKE "%Web Developer%" 
group by `resumes`.`id` 
having (relevance_1 + relevance_2) > 0 
order by (relevance_1 + relevance_2) DESC, resumes.job_title ASC
```

Comment: I don't know if this can help but I just ran into the same issue : `->get()` returning no result but manually executing `->toSql()` and replacing values in raw SQL did. The problem was the value in my `LIKE` statement. Be sure you got the correct value in your `$filter['filter_job_title']` variable (the same as when you manually edit `->toSql()` query

Comment: @micster, thanks for the heads up.  I changed my LIKE statement and 
 MATCH codes and its working now.   `$k = !empty($filter['filter_keyword']) ? \DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($filter['filter_keyword']) : "";` `return $query->where('resume_section_experiences.exp_job_title', 'LIKE', "%" . $filter['filter_job_title'] . "%");     `